# Server is not able to print data getting from client

Tags: c++, linux, server, client

My client code sends some data to the server when it connects to it and I want that data to be printed by the server on the screen.But it is giving quite a strange out not what I am sending. Here is my server and client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "server.h"

Server::Server()
{

}

void Server::CreateSocket()
{
server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(server_sockfd < 0)
{
    std::cout <<  "Error creating socket\n"<<std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
std::cout << "Server socket created\n" <<std::endl;
}

void Server::NameSocket()
{
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server_address.sin_port = htons(1500);

if((bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)& server_address, sizeof(server_address)))<0)
{
    std::cout<<"Error binding socket\n"<<std::endl;
    exit(1);
}

std::cout <<"Server naming done \n"<<std::endl;
}

void Server::CreateQueue()
{
listen(server_sockfd, 1);
std::cout <<"Server Create queue done \n"<<std::endl;
}

void Server::AcceptConnection()
{
size = sizeof(server_address);
client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&server_address, &size);
if(client_sockfd < 0)
{
    std::cout << "Can't accept connection\n"<<std::endl;
    exit(1);
}

std::cout <<"Server accept connection done"<<std::endl;
}

void Server::ReadWriteSocket()
{
while(true)
{
    char *buffer;
    // Server reading data coming from the client
    read(client_sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    //std::cout <<buffer<<std::endl;( Problem Comes here )

    // Server writing data to the client
    //write(client_sockfd, & buffer1,sizeof(buffer1));
    //std::cout << buffer1<<std::endl;
    close(client_sockfd);
}
}
```

Client Code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "client.h"


   Client::Client()
  {
    this->_Flag = false;
  }


// Create a socket for client
void Client::CreateSocket()
{
   if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)
{
    perror("Socket not created");
    exit(1);
}

std::cout << "Client Socket created \n"<<std::endl;
}
//Name socket as agreed with a server
void Client::NameSocket()
{
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
address.sin_port = htons(1500);
std::cout<<"Client name socket done \n"<<std::endl;
}

void Client::ConnectSocket()
{
 // Now connect out socket to server socket
result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));
if(result == -1)
{
    std::cout << "Can't establish connection\n"<<std::endl;
    exit(1);
}

 std::cout << "Connect to server socket done \n"<<std::endl;
}
// We can now read and write via sockfd
void Client::ReadWriteSocket()
{
  char *buffer= "Hello from the client";
_Flag = true;
while(_Flag)
{
write(sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
std::cout <<buffer<<std::endl;
//std::cout<<buffer1<<std::endl;
//read(sockfd,& buffer, sizeof(buffer));
close(sockfd);
}
```

}

input : Hello from the client

output should be same but instead I am getting:
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��
�������U�����D$��

Comment: Yet again, failure to handle fully, and correctly, the result returned by read().  You have completely ignored it.  You cannot do that.

Comment: Ohwait, it's worse - you have not allocated 'char *buffer;', and 'sizeof(buffer)' does not do what you think it does.:(

Comment: Not looked at client code yet - it's probaby got the same issues:(

Comment: 'Any solution' - what?  I've just given you two huge bugs.  Have you fixed them and re-tested?

Comment: Fix, re-test and then, if you still have problems, edit in your changed  code, error details etc. underneath your question above.  NOTE:  not 'in place of'.  Don't edit the original question - just add to it, (or ask another question).

Comment: Have another hint or two: You MUST supply a valid buffer pointer to read().  'char *buffer;' is an uninitialized pointer, and reading into it's target address is UB and will segfault if you are lucky.    You MUST correctly the result returned by read(). The result returned by read() is the ONLY way to determine how much data has been loaded into your buffer, (if any). The other attempts: various combinations of bzero, memset, sizeof, strlen() etc. that are often seen on SO, are not generally safe to use for that purpose.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Do not add tags for unrelated languages!

Comment: @Olaf, sockets i am using is a part of C.

Comment: @user1882840: Please point at where the C standard even mentions sockets. POSIX is not part of the C standard. Anyway, your code is C++, you use C++. Maybe you can add sockets tag, but not C.

Answer (score -1):

In the method `Server::ReadWriteSocket()`

```
write(sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
std::cout <<buffer<<std::endl;
```

you print the buffer which has no ending zero to mark string end (another problem is that `buffer` does not have memory reserved, so the server could crash). Thus, it prints any random bytes found in buffer after the content. Also, check the number of bytes returned by `read` and use it to determine end of the `buffer`.
The same holds for `Client::ReadWriteSocket()`.

Comment: Doesn't sound right. "received over write"? That doesn't make sense. The `write` call does not change `buffer` contents at all. In the code you pointed out the real error is that `sizeof (buffer)` needs to be `strlen (buffer) + 1` and `&buffer` needs to be `buffer`.

Comment: You're right, I've meant over `read`... editing the response.

Comment: @kaylum you are right,it should be buffer only since it is a pointer. But still it doesn't work it shows me the same response like before. The problem is at the receiving end because I am not specifying how long is my data. Since at the server side buffer doesn't point to anything. There should be some condition which should break the msg into data 1 and data2.

Comment: @user1882840 Of course fixing that alone doesn't work. Your problem is both ends. I was only commenting on the code snippet shown in this answer.